# Redirect Jmeter to the home page after successful login

Tags: redirect, jmeter

I am trying to create a jmeter test script. For login, I make a POST request to the

> https://www..com/authenticate

with valid parameters. On the browser, when I fill the form fields and submit, on successful login it redirects me to the

> https://www..com/objects/index

page. But this is failing in jmeter. I get a 301: Moved Permanently in the response. How do I make jmeter redirect post login. I tried adding the second url as a different  What am I doing wrong here?

Note- I have tried different combinations of Redirect Automatically and Follow redirects but nothing helped.

Comment: The fact that "Follow redirects" did not help means that your problem is not in redirect but something else. Maybe you are not preserving cookies? Or not including the right headers?

Comment: Thanks @Kiril ! You are right. Redirection is not an issue. The authentication had troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not with redirection. The authentication was not going through as I was sending the header in a wrong sequence. Resolved the issue on correcting the order.

Answer (score 1):

can't you use another request of type GET to reproduce the scenario ? + adding a Cookie manager so the session continues ? Something like this : [image]

(First request is a POST - where you post your login data)

(Second one is GET - where you get the index page or the one that follows the login)

You could also check [this](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E301.html) there is an explanation what might be wrong in the code (corrupt redirection chain or something) check it out

Comment: The second GET is going back to the login page. Not working for me.